# Back end for Image Carousel PHP Mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, photo

I dont really have an idea on how to make this photo carousels backend, Pease, give an advice.This is the website im working with http://mabini150.net23.net/ Here the code:

```
<div class="da-slide">
<h2>MABINI@150 Softlaunch@FAITH</h2>
<p>Mabini @150 with the commemoration of First Asia Institute Of      Technology and
Humanities.Visit the 
<a
href="Gallery.php">Gallery Page</a> for more photos.</p>
<div class="da-img"><img src="css/images/FaithMabini/1.jpg" alt="image01" /></div>
</div>

<div class="da-slide">
<h2>MABINI SHRINE VIRTUAL TOUR</h2>
<p>The Mabini Shrine Tanauan contains a museum and a library, designed by National
Artist for Architecture Juan
F.Nakpil.Visit the <a href="VirtualTour.php">Virtual Tour</a> and
feel like you're in the shrine.</p>
<div class="da-img"><img src="css/images/Mabini/virtual.PNG" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Backend? what exactly do you mean by that? Do you want to pass data from your server-side or ?

Comment: I am making a content management System for a website, and i want to make my photo carousel dynamic, so the admin/user can update it.

Comment: Create your photo gallery post or something and pass the data to the db (make sure you store your photos in a folder not the db).
Query the data from the db and insert that result into your html (carousel). Can I ask if you are using any framework? e.g. this can easily be done in Codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

make a database table which contain all things which you want to add with image 
eg (`<P> <h2> <a href>`) with particular column name eg . for `<P>` =about  and for `<h2>`= heading and link for anchor tag and then on your main page fetch from database and then create a dynamic slider as below

```
       $query = 'select * from table';
      $result = mysql_query($query);
      while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
     {
     echo '<div class="da-slide">';
     echo '<h2>'.$row['heading'].'</h2>';
     echo '<p>'.$row['about'].'</p>';
     echo '<div class="da-img"><img src="'.$row['image'].'" alt="image01" /></div>
      </div>';
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response sir, but what i really want to know is how to create the user interface for the admin. btw im using CKEDitor.

Comment: I want to know how to insert data like that one in my  database

Comment: [link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp) you should try some tutorial..

Comment: i may say i'm on intermediate level on php, i all know the basics. What i'm having difficulty with is the Approach